# librdf raptor deal with integer value in object

Tags: c++, rdf

I got an error when there is an integer value in the ntriples' object. how can I get the integer value directly? Instead of got an error. Thank you.

Details:

1. the rdf triple

   `<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.124x8gtbc> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/measurement_unit.dated_percentage.rate>     1.27    .`
2. code

follow is my code.

```
void process_nt_file(string file_path, raptor_statement_handler pro_handler){
  unsigned char *uri_string;
  raptor_uri *uri, *base_uri;
  raptor_parser *rdf_parser;
  
  raptor_world *world = raptor_new_world();
  rdf_parser = raptor_new_parser(world, "ntriples");
  raptor_parser_set_statement_handler(rdf_parser, NULL, pro_handler);
  
  uri_string = raptor_uri_filename_to_uri_string(file_path.c_str());
  uri = raptor_new_uri(world, uri_string);
  base_uri = raptor_uri_copy(uri);

  time_t start_t, end_t;
  time(&start_t);
  
  raptor_parser_parse_file(rdf_parser, uri, base_uri);
  
  time(&end_t);
  double diff_time = difftime(end_t, start_t);
  printf("Duration: %.2lf s", diff_time);
  
  raptor_free_parser(rdf_parser);
}
```

Comment: http://librdf.org/raptor/

Comment: Your question is unanswerable in its current form because you haven't told us how to reproduce the problem.  Show a minimal sample of the data that causes the issue, the code you are using and the error message you receive.  You can use the `edit` button under your question to add extra details

Comment: I have added some details, thank you for telling me. I have thought I described clearly enough.

Comment: @dreamszl what exactly is raptor statement handler. and should I use it in the code? do you have an example?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your data is not valid NTriples so `libraptor` is quite correct in rejecting it.  Your data fragment is using a syntactic compression called plain literals which is not valid in NTriples.

This compression is actually from the [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) format (which is a super-set of NTriples) so you need to parse your data as Turtle instead.

So instead of this line:

```
rdf_parser = raptor_new_parser(world, "ntriples");
```

Use this line:

```
rdf_parser = raptor_new_parser(world, "turtle");
```

Note that the Freebase data is notorious for containing much invalid data so even with this change you may still run into errors.